# Load Gmail API in new tab without re-authorising | Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I'm trying the following to try and check if the the user is already authorised, but I dont understand it enough, and I think I'm checking the wrong thing.

**Background.js**

```
var SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

function tryAuth() {
    chrome.cookies.get({url:'https://accounts.google.com', name:'LSID'}, function(cookie) {
        var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        if (cookie) {
            gapi.client.init('gmail', 'v1',{
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: SCOPE,
                immediate: 'false'
            });

        }else{
            console.log("trying oauth");
            var configString = {
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: SCOPE,
                immediate: 'false'
            };

           return gapi.auth.authorize(configString, handleAuthResult);
        }
    });
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.log("AUTH RESULT!!");
    console.log(authResult);
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        var access_token = authResult.access_token;
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', gmailAPILoaded);
    }
}
```

*This*, however, works fine, but it re-authorises each time a page is refreshed or a new tab is opened, and I get a popup opens and closes in a loop (I assume it's iterating through each tab I have open?):

```
function tryAuth() {
    var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    console.log("trying oauth");
        var configString = {
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: SCOPE,
            immediate: 'false'
        };
    return gapi.auth.authorize(configString, handleAuthResult);
}
```

I'm also using `"matches":"<all_urls>"` in the manifest, which I know is a contributing factor because I can specify URL's and it only flashes a popup once for authorisation.

Any help would be awesome guys.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The rest of the code is under NDA and I cant post it. The above code would be enough for someone to understand what I am doing and ultimately was for a Chrome Extension developer on Upwork, surprisingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `immediate: "true"` using my first example, and everything is now
 working.